# React: Parsing error: Identifier 'publicKey' has already been declared

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React so please bear with my naming conventions:

How can I use the same name of 2 props from two different 3rd party components?

```
import { useWallet} from "@solana/wallet-adapter-react";
import { useMoralis } from "react-moralis";

export const SendOneLamportToRandomAddress = () => {
   const { publicKey, sendTransaction } = useWallet();
   const { publicKey } = useMoralis();
}
```

It looks as if `{publicKey as pK}` won't work and neither does `{pK : publicKey}`

What am I missing?

thanks

Comment: What's wrong with `const otherPublicKey = useMoralis().publicKey`?

Comment: You're missing how to rename destructured vars; the "real" name is first, then the "alias": `const { publicKey: moralisPublicKey } = useMoralis()`. I'd rename both to eliminate confusion in the mainline code, e.g., `walletKey` and `moralisKey` or whatever.